# Why we need Socks Proxy?

Tags: firewall, proxy, socks

Is there any specific reason for customers to choose SOCKS proxy when compared to HTTP Proxy?

Comment: SOCKS can support UDP as well as TCP, also can accept incoming connections with the SOCKS BIND command in SOCKS5.  An HTTP proxy can be used for general TCP connections to other ports (with the CONNECT method), but can only do outbound connections.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't want to proxy HTTP traffic.

Comment: Or when you want to proxy HTTP **and** other TCP traffic but want to keep your proxy as simple as possible. (One software is easier to maintain than two.)